Module not found error when using stream-chat-react with Next JS 12
import { Chat } from 'stream-chat-react';

function Chats ({streamToken, user}) {

const [chatsClient, setChatsClient] = useState<StreamChat>(StreamChat.getInstance('API_KEY'));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chatsClient && user.id) {
      chatsClient.connectUser({ id: user.id }, streamToken);
    }

  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        {chatsClient ? <Chat client={chatsClient}></Chat> : <div>Loading...</div>}
    </div>
  )
}

When running the above code I am getting error response of
./node_modules/@react-aria/interactions/dist/usePress.mjs:3:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '@swc/helpers/_/_class_private_field_get'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@react-aria/interactions/dist/import.mjs
./node_modules/@react-aria/focus/dist/useFocusable.mjs
./node_modules/@react-aria/focus/dist/import.mjs
./node_modules/stream-chat-react/dist/components/Modal/Modal.js
./node_modules/stream-chat-react/dist/components/Modal/index.js
./node_modules/stream-chat-react/dist/components/index.js
./node_modules/stream-chat-react/dist/index.js
./pages/pro/chats/index.tsx

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

I have tried to install @swc/helpers package
"@swc/helpers": "^0.5.12",

I have also tried to check the compatibility of "stream-chat-react" with Next JS 12
I have also tried to configure next.config.ts
webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
  // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module
  if (!isServer) {
    config.resolve.fallback.fs = false;
  }
  return config;
},


Hello, did you fix the error?
